# Idimoatic method of running spark notebook prototyped code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Once I've prototyped my Scala code using Spark notebook I then copy the relevant cells to a script file that I invoke from Apache Spark CLI. Is there a more idiomatic way of performing this that aids code re-use ?

So instead of creating a script file from the spark notebook run the notebook itself via an api call ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it *is* possible to run your scala code directly on a spark cluster via Jupyter (IPython) scala notebook!

I've done it and it involves:

**Cloudera Livy**

**Jupyter Notebook**

**Spark Magic ("sparkmagic.magics")**

**A Spark Cluster**

Another option if you're interested in a bit more plug and play style is using Apache Zeppelin instead of Jupyter Notebook, because Zeppelin natively and rather seamlessly integrates with Spark. Each approach has its merits...

EDIT:
Regarding the API call question, you can also use the Livy (livy.io) API and clients to create/update/interact with/etc livy sessions.